# Can I convert my query result to a string using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a simple LINQ query below. Name is the only column in the database together with ID as the primary key.

```
 var query = from b in db.Database
                    where b.Name == "myrssfeed/rss"
                    select b;
```

Is there a way of converting 'myrssfeed/rss' to a string?

Comment: isn't it already a string?

Comment: Don't understand. It's already a string, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean? `"Paul_O'brien"` already is a string.

Comment: Try with: 
`if(query.Any()){  string name = query.First().Name;  }`

Comment: @MrMins or he can just select b.Name instead of b

Comment: Are you asking how to select the name instead of the object? Just use `select b.Name`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that returns a `IEnumerable<string>` or not a `string`

Comment: To which you can apply `First()`, *without* loading the entire object first. By using `query.First()` you force a query that will return all fields when you only need a single field.

Comment: `"myrssfeed/rss"` is a string as well. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to store rss feeds into a database but my xmlreader will not accept the result unless it is a string

Comment: Much appreciate the quick response. Seems like I will need to post a new quest with all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Paul_O'brien" is a string, but your Linq query is not returning a string, it's returning an `IEnumerable<whatever type b is>`. So you need to select the name and tell it there's only one result.

```
var paul = (from b in db.Database
                where b.Name == "Paul_O'brien"
                select b.Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

Otherwise, you could iterate through the strings.

```
var names = from b in db.Database
                    where b.Name == "myrssfeed/rss"
                    select b.Name;

foreach(var name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: You are still returning the object, not the `Name` property. Did you mean to write `select b.Name`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I didn't even notice he wasn't selecting the name.

Comment: That's why this question makes no sense.

Comment: A big thank you @mason it was the SingleorDefault method that was the solution to my problem. Sorry for the syntax errors Panagiotis I am very new to programming

Answer (score 0):

To get a collection of strings the following will do it

```
 IEnumerable<string> names = from b in db.Database
                    where b.Name == "Paul_O'brien"
                    select b.Name;
```

And if your only expecting one the following will work

```
string name = (from b in db.Database
                        where b.Name == "Paul_O'brien"
                        select b.Name).Single();
```